# Echoed div backgroun-image style option wokrs in IE but doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: php, background-image

Ok, I'm probably the first one who has something working in IE and doesn't in Chrome, so here is a code that you need.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {   
     $img = $row['img'];
     define ('SITE_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
     $imageLocation = SITE_ROOT."images/articlePics/$img";
     $posts .= "<div  class='newArticle' style='background-image:url($imageLocation)'></div>";
}
echo $posts;
}
```

Comment: what does your rendered html look like in IE/Chrome? what happens if there is no defined $row['img'] or that file does not exists?

Comment: let me check, thats a good question :)

Comment: also are you seeing anything reported in your document inspector error log `F12`?

Comment: I have in Chrome, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: which asset is causing that error? can you post the rendered html here please

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/images/articlePics/3.jpg

Comment: this one is related not the other one, sorry my mestake

Comment: post you html I cannot help unless i can see what your php is returning. Last ask.

Comment: I found the solution, but with your help, I'm using xammp and Chrome doesn't allow some local files to be uploaded for security reasons, so i need to pass that flag, here is the link:

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html

Comment: post it as an answer to your own question. to help others and future you if you come across it again

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't allow some local files to be uploaded for security reasons, so you need to pass that flag, here is the link:

http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/windows.html

**On Windows Operating System**

1. Get the url of your Chrome Installation **path to your chrome installation** e.g C:\Users-your-user-name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application>
2. Launch the Google Chrome browser from the command line window with the additional argument **‘–allow-file-access-from-files’.** E.g **‘path to your chrome installation\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files’**
3. **Temporary method you can use each time you are testing**

   - Copy the existing chrome launcher
   - Do as above and save it with a new name e.g chrome - testing
   - Alternatively, you can simply create a new launcher with the above and use it to start chrome.